# What's the meaning of " path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container" " in a .classpath file?

Tags: java, classpath, buildpath

I am trying to understand how Eclipse Build Path works.

It seems what I configured in the `Build Path` window is stored in the `.classpath` file. I see entries like these in this file:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>

<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Java/jars/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar"/>

<classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>
```

I can understand the `lib` and `src` kinds of class path entries because their `path` attribute values look like a valid path.

But how does the `con` kind class path entry work? Its `path` value looks like a package name rather than a valid path. What does it mean? How does it work?

Comment: It is a predefined library, like jUnit, maven container, ... It is defined by that class for that project (and other project settings), in that case most probably your installed server's runtime is in its content.

Comment: What's the difference between a `predefined library` and some `necessary JAR I download form web`?

Comment: The predefined library can be specific to the workspace, and managed by an extension. The jar you download from the web, can also be a user library and specific to the workspace, but in that case you have to take care of the changes.